# Compile Error: No such column 'What' on entity 'Task'

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, compile-error

I have written a trigger on case, to prevent closing the case when all the associated tasks are not closed.

Facing this error while saving the trigger:

> Error: Compile Error: No such column 'What' on entity 'Task'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 7 column 18

Here is my trigger.

```
trigger updateCase on Case (before update) 
{

    Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();


    for(Task t : [SELECT Id, What FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND What IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])
    {
        taskMap.put(What, t);
    }


    for(Case c : Trigger.new)
    {

        if(taskMap.containsKey(c.Id) && c.IsClosed && c.IsClosed != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).IsClosed)
            c.addError('Case Cannot be closed with open tasks');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual field is called `WhatId`. Your query should be more like:

```
SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE ...
```

You also have the same issue on the next line, in addition to not even referencing the record. It should have at least been `t.What`, but since the field is `WhatId`, you need `t.WhatId` instead.

```
for (Task record : [SELECT WhatId FROM Task WHERE ...])
    taskMap.put(record.WhatId, record);
```